# How to force developers to write CustomAnnotation before each api Springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**How can we force developer to write **Developed Custom-annotation** on rest api**

**Example :**
We Developed annotation Called : **ValidatePermission**

what we need to do , displaying runtime error for developer that he missing annotation **@ValidatePermission** on API , when he tried to write new api

```
@ValidatePermission 
@GetMapping("/details")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('902')")
public ResponseEntity<CustDtlsInqDto> getCustomerDetails(@CurrentUser UserPrincipal currentUser,
        @RequestParam(name = "poiNumber", required = false) String poiNumber,
        @RequestParam(name = "cif", required = false) String cif) {

    return ResponseEntity.ok(customerService.getCustomerDetailsByPoiOrCif(currentUser.getId(), poiNumber, cif));
}
```

Comment: Why dont you use Arch Unit to enforce this kind of Architectural decissions?? https://www.archunit.org/getting-started . I think is possible to enforce that classes that belong to certain package, should be annotatted with certain annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Annotations usage cannot be forced in any way before or on compilation (at least I am not aware of any technique, feel free to correct me).

The only way to go is to perform a check-up during the unit testing phase. Simply write an **unit test** that scans through the REST API definition beans and its public methods (or annotated) to check up using teh [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) whether an annotation from a particular category (implementation details up to you) is present within the formal parameters of methods.

- [Gits Github: Find all annotated classes in a package using Spring](https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/a34480c1bcc31c45da730c48c4f41331)
- [Baeldung: A Guide to the Reflections Library](https://www.baeldung.com/reflections-library)

Answer (score 0):

Something looks to me weird in this approach.
So you say:

> ...displaying runtime error for developer that he missing annotation @ValidatePermission on API

Based on this phrase, let me suggest an alternative:

So the developer that runs the project locally (during the debugging session or maybe tests) should see an error if he/she didn't put the annotation on the methods of rest controller, right?

If so, Why don't you need the developers to put this annotation?

**The main idea of my suggestion is: Why not letting spring to do it for you automatically?**

You could implement some kind of aspect or if you don't want to use a spring aop and prefer 'raw plain spring', [BeanPostProcessor](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-beanpostprocessor), that would 'wrap' all the methods of class annotated with RestContoller (by creating a run-time proxy) and before running a controller method will executed the logic that was supposed to be supported by the annotation?

In the case of Web MVC, another approach is to implement an interceptor that will be invoked automatically by spring mvc engine and you'll be able to execute any custom logic you want there, you'll also be able to inject other beans (like auxiliary services) into the interceptor.

Read [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor) in case you're not familiar with these interceptors, you'll need `preHandle` methods as far as I understand.